# Easy way to handle AcceptMessageSessionAsync and ReceiveAsync

Tags: c#-4.0, task-parallel-library, servicebus, azureservicebus

Attempting to jump into the Windows Server ServiceBus 1.1 code-base along with adopting the new TPL async methods.  But I could not find an easy way to just spin up N number of handlers for message sessions (might have 100 or so concurrent sessions).  So it would be great to get some feedback on the following code, any suggestions on an easier way would be great... note tried to keep code sample simple for the questions purpose.

```
///example usage
SubscriptionClient subClient = SubscriptionClient.Create(TopicName, SubscriptionName);

subClient.HandleSessions(5, msg =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Processing recived Message: SessionId = {0}, Body = {1}",
                msg.SessionId,
                msg.GetBody<string>()));
            msg.Complete();
        });


public static class SubscriptionClientExtensions
{
    public static void HandleSessions (this SubscriptionClient sc, Int32 numberOfSessions, Action<BrokeredMessage> handler)
    {
        Action<Task<MessageSession>> sessionAction = null;
        Action<Task<BrokeredMessage>> msgHandler = null;

        sessionAction = new Action<Task<MessageSession>>(tMS =>
        {
            if (tMS.IsFaulted) // session timed out - repeat
            {
                sc.AcceptMessageSessionAsync().ContinueWith(sessionAction);
                return;
            }

            MessageSession msgSession = null;
            try
            {
                msgSession = tMS.Result;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return; // task cancelation exception
            }

            msgHandler = new Action<Task<BrokeredMessage>>(taskBM =>
            {
                if (taskBM.IsFaulted)
                    return;

                BrokeredMessage bMsg = null;
                try
                {
                    bMsg = taskBM.Result;
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    return; // task cancelation exception
                }

                if (bMsg == null)
                {
                    sc.AcceptMessageSessionAsync().ContinueWith(sessionAction); // session is dead
                    return;
                }

                handler(bMsg); // client code to handle the message

                msgSession.ReceiveAsync(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)).ContinueWith(msgHandler); // repeat
            });

            msgSession.ReceiveAsync(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)).ContinueWith(msgHandler); // start listening
        });

        for (Int32 nIndex = 0; nIndex < numberOfSessions; nIndex++)
        {
            sc.AcceptMessageSessionAsync().ContinueWith(sessionAction);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. Why are you not using `async-await`? You can do that in .net 4.0 with BCL.Async.

Comment: 2. Is there a problem with the code? If there isn't one this question belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks for informing me of the code-review site - will post there - but the main question still sits, seems like there should be an easier way to construct N number of listeners/handlers for message sessions - just like OnMessage with MessageOptions - and the sample code does work..